# Tool for drawing relationship graph with UI

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, drawing

I'm looking for a tools that helps you draw relationship graphs using a simple UI, with ability to put pictures inside nodes and describe relations.

It will be used mainly to represent relations between people using their photos like this :

[image: graph sample]

The following features would be good things to have :

- Exporting/Importing graphs using xml/json/csv... .
- Can be used offline (on windows)

Can you recommend a tool that does something similar to this ?